# Android repeating alarm, override self on each open

Tags: android, android-alarms

I have the below alarm that gets run from the MainActivity on app launch. I think I have programmed it to override itself on each new app launch. But I am finding it hard to test. Is this indeed overriding itself OR if I close and open the app a bunch of times will I have numerous alarms?

How do I test how many alarms I have created?

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 5000, 60000, pendingIntent);
    }
```

So for `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Context context, int requestCode, Intent intent, int flags)`

- `requestCode` is? (I assume set an ID for the alarm, which you can override with a new alarm)
- `flags` do? (Tell the alarm what to do if the new alarm has the same ID?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you override it, since you use the same request code every time you the activity is created. The requestcode is the second paramater the PendingIntent.getBrodacast() method and operates like the id of you alarm to update it later (for excample cancel it). You can check if your alarm is already set with this code:

```
boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, 
        new Intent("com.my.package.MY_UNIQUE_ACTION"), 
        PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
```

However you don't set the alarm with your code you need toc call:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 0 ,pendingIntent);
```

to actually set the alarm.

To your last question, there are several options how you can use a flag:

> int FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT  Flag indicating that if the described
>   PendingIntent already exists, the current one should be canceled
>   before generating a new one.
>
> int   FLAG_IMMUTABLE  Flag indicating that the created PendingIntent
>   should be immutable.
>
> int   FLAG_NO_CREATE  Flag> indicating that if the described
>   PendingIntent does not already exist,
>   then simply return null instead of creating it.
>
> int   FLAG_ONE_SHOT  Flag indicating that this PendingIntent can be used
>   only once.
>
> int   FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT  Flag indicating that if the described
>   PendingIntent already exists, then keep it but replace its extra data
>   with what is in this new Intent.

Comment: Does that mean that "PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT" is pointless or is that the instruction for things with the same request code?

Comment: Another user pointed out what you wrote earlier. I forgot to paste a piece of the code.

Comment: So as the IDs (requestCodes) match android then looks to the flag for instruction? If I want the alarm to be overridden if it exists do I keep my current flag of FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or do I use FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT?

Comment: Yes. If you want your current alarm to be overriden you use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT. However if you parse 0 als flag the result will be the same. As If you create multiple alarms with same id, the most recent one will cancel the previous.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can set the alarm in Android for a particular time:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
final int _id = Integer.parseInt(""+MCZManagers.timeToMillies(alarmTime));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, _id, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, MCZManagers.dateTimeToMillies(alarmDateTime), pendingIntent);
```

As soon as you destroy the app, the alarm will also get destroyed and won't play again.

Comment: You aren't answering my question.

Comment: Yes it will override itself every time you open the app. if you see in the above code, I am setting a particular id for the Alarm so that it won't get overrided.

Comment: I want there to only ever be a single repeating alarm. Never more.

Comment: The you can use this for repeating alarms:  alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, MCZManagers.dateTimeToMillies(alarmDateTime), 2*60*60, pendingIntent);